# asp.net :does dot net platform 3.5 impose any limit on number of thread of threads to be run at a time if it does what is limit?

Tags: asp.net, performance, multithreading, limit

hey i am using threads on my own not using thread pool.each thread is making web request .so is there any restriction from platform side fr number of threads to be used .or it will just degrade performance ?

Comment: Are you using the threads from a .NET website or console/windows app. If not a web project then your asp.net tag is irelevant

Comment: module which is creating threads is part of back end project.
bt i am refering this module in asp.net website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit aside from the physical limitations of the computer.

[Heres an article with a little more detail.](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/29/444912.aspx)